# Why trailing comma doesn't add undefined to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Was writing a function that takes in an array of numbers and returns true and the index if there is a missing number or false if there are no missing numbers. 
I Just noticed something about arrays that confuses me.

An array like

```
[,1,2,3,4]
```

will print

```
[undefined,1,2,3,4]
```

The array starts with a comma, Output makes sense to me

But why does

```
[1,2,3,4,] // Notice that the array ends with a comma
```

print

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I would have assumed the output would be `[1,2,3,4,undefined]`.

Does anyone know why this is so?

Answer (score 8):

The trailing comma ("elision") is ignored:

> If an element is elided at the end of an array, that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-array-initializer

Note that only one comma is stipped on the right, so this `[1,2,,]` will be rendered as `[1,2,undefined]`.

In Javascript arrays are just objects with a special `length` property, and an array initializer like

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

is a shortcut for

```
{
    "0": 'a', 
    "1": 'b', 
    "2": 'c',
    "length": 3
}
```

An elision makes the initializer skip the next index and increases the overall `length`, so this

```
['a', 'b', , 'c']
```

becomes this:

```
{
    "0": 'a', 
    "1": 'b', 
    "3": 'c'
    "length": 4
}
```

and two trailing elisions

```
['a', 'b', 'c', , ]
```

become

```
{
    "0": 'a', 
    "1": 'b', 
    "2": 'c', 
    "length": 4
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is true `In Javascript arrays are just objects with a special length property`. From what point of view is this statement true? The user-facing API ?

Comment: @Cristy: see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-arraycreate, point 6

Comment: But it also "inherits" all the `Array.prototype` methods, so length is not the only difference as stated.

Comment: That is so weird but thanks for giving me a perspective.

Answer (score 1):

`[,1,2,3,4]` doesn't create `[undefined,1,2,3,4]`. It creates `[empty, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. It's a sparse array with a *hole* at the beginning.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Arrays) for [Trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas):

> JavaScript ignores trailing commas in arrays. JavaScript has allowed trailing commas in array literals since the beginning, and later added them to object literals (ECMAScript 5) and most recently (ECMAScript 2017) to function parameters.

But, if more than one trailing comma is used, a hole is produced:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3,,,];
console.log(arr.length) // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The array would actually turn out to be `[empty,1,2,3,4]`, here `empty` is basically a **memory hole**. This is an entry that has lost its memory reference. Link for detailed explanation is here

[holes-arrays-es6](http://2ality.com/2015/09/holes-arrays-es6.html)